# Problem with adding figure

Tags: floats

I am trying to add a figure. the code is compiled without any error, but in output file figure is not fitted well and is placed over text and in two column. Can anyone help me?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
        \includegraphics{solpro.pdf}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This query is going be virtually impossible to answer in its current form, since the information you've provided is highly incomplete. Please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that gives rise to the problem behavior you wish to fix. Incidentally, I see you've posted three questions to date and haven't "accepted" any of the answers given to your questions. By accepting an answer, you indicate that it's been particularly useful.

Comment: How can i accept an answer? I can not see anything special for accepting answers.

Comment: Use the `Checkmark-Symbol` ...  [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Presumably the image you are including is wider than the column, try `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{solpro.pdf}`

Comment: I removed the wrapfigure tag as your example does not use it, if you wanted a wrapfigure example, feel free to add the tag back, but change your example to use that environment.

Comment: If you are working in two columns try `figure*` instead of `figure`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle-Thanks for helping me. How width is any column?Do you know that precisely?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle- what does do the 'keepaspectratio=true' in '\includegraphics'?

Comment: @skpblack- Thanks for helping me. What is the different? My figure is lactated in two column and over my text.!!

Comment: @skpblack-By using figure* the problem with overwriting was solved but it fill two column still.

Comment: Your comment is not very clear, `[width=\linewidtdth]` makes the image be scaled to the width of the text in the current column. If you want the image in one column not two you want `figure` not `figure*` you do not need `keepaspectratio` here it's just needed if you specify height and width

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the image you are including is wider than the column.

Using

```
\begin{figuure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{solpro.pdf} 
 \caption{my figure}
\end[figure}
```

will scale the image to be no wider than the column.

Comment: Thanks. Now my problem is that the caption is so far behind the figure. How can i shorten this distance between caption and figure?

Comment: latex adds only a small space there `\abovecaptionskip` defaulting to 10pt, if you have a lot of space there is probably white space in the image, you can use trim and clip options of `\includegraphics` to only show th epart you want. as a test put `\fbox{..}` around the image, if the white space is inside the box, it is party of the image not being added by latex